# How do I check if a process is running from c++ code?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ app that will communicate with another process via boost::interprocess, however I need to check if the other process is actually running first - as the other process is responsible for creating the inter-process shared memory. How do I check if the other process is running ?

folks, I'm specifically required to check other processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The managed_shared_memory ctor will throw an interprocess_exception in case it fails to open the given shared memory (assuming you passed open_only to the ctor). You could use the error code in the exception to test whether the shared memory is available or not.

All means to check whether a process is running (by looking at the process tree, testing for magic log files or whatever) suffer from a race condition which occurs if the remote process is running, but it didn't yet manage to setup the shared memory.

**Update:** If you *only* want to check whether a process is being executed by the operating system, then you need to walk the list of processes and consider each one. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can find an example how to do that.

A much easier, more portable, but less precise technique is to use lock files. Process A creates a magic 'lock file' in some location on startup, and deletes it as it terminates. Process B can then test for the existence of this file to determine whether Process A is running. A null-byte size file would be sufficient for this, but the file could also contain additional information which is helpful to Process B (such as the PID of Process A). However, there's a short time window at the very beginning of Process A at which no lock file exists - yet the process is running.

Comment: If you use lock files beware if process A crashes and leaves it's lock file hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

you can either use mutex or try to open the shared memory file and handle the exception.

Comment: Yes, but I'm specifically required to check the running processes

Comment: @M. Utku: A mutex test is fine if you control both applications, because Mutexs will normally be released if the application which opened them closes.  That said, I prefer Frerich's solution, assuming the *normal* case is that both applications are running.